# Save remote XML Feed as local file... Corruption?

Tags: php, xml

I have an external web service outputting an XML feed.
I need to grab the XML feed and save it as a local file.. (approx 3mb)

Currently Im using the following code:

```
<?PHP
$url = "https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/ae0324ff-e1a5-4a77-9783-f41248bfa975/boats?status=on";
copy($url, "download.xml");
?>
```

and its working... it saves the XML feed as a local file.  However, its slightly corrupted in the sense that the 'returns' or 'newlines' have been stripped out. The script that reads the local XML does not work with the download.xml  because of these changes.

For example.. it should look like this:

```
<ApplicationArea>
<Sender>
<LogicalID>IMT</LogicalID>
<TaskID>Inventory Sync</TaskID>
<CreatorNameCode>IMT Exporter</CreatorNameCode>
<SenderNameCode>IMT</SenderNameCode>
</Sender>
```

and not like this...

```
<ApplicationArea><Sender><LogicalID>IMT</LogicalID><TaskID>Inventory Sync</TaskID><CreatorNameCode>IMT Exporter</CreatorNameCode><SenderNameCode>IMT</SenderNameCode></Sender>
```

I am not a programmer and have no idea how to fix this or if it can be!! 
If I was to open Chrome and browse to to xml feed, save it as .xml and upload to the server, it works fine.

Can someone help me write a script that will safely download the XML feed without corrupting it?!!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what this script does and why you say it is "breaking"? This newline difference should *not* be breaking any XML processing script--it is not significant whitespace for this kind of XML file.

Comment: The script loads in data from the xml file, which is actually a list of boats for sale.  When the xml contents has no returns after each line,  the script does not seem to produce any output.  Well, infact it errors with "we dont have what you are looking for at the moment" etc.

Comment: Are you certain that this is a newline problem? And not that maybe the file isn't where the script can find it? Or maybe it doesn't have permission to read the file created by the `copy()` script?

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe that there is a corruption going on here.

Pull up **view-source**:https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/ae0324ff-e1a5-4a77-9783-f41248bfa975/boats?status=on

As you can see, that source is not exactly peppered with newlines after blocks. I didn't see your example block `(<ApplicationArea>)`, but there are plenty to suggest that what you think is proper whitespace is just formatting introduced by chrome, and not the source file.

Anyhow, not sure why you want it formatted like that (unless you're string parsing instead of XML) but way to fix this is by using the **tidy** extension (must be configured in PHP).

```
$xml = file_get_contents( "https://..." ); // your url here

// look up other tidy options to get a satisfactory format
$options = array(
    "input-xml" => true,
    "indent" => true,
    "wrap" => "160",
    "output-xml" => true,
);

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($xml, $options);

$tidy->cleanRepair();
```

At this point, save or preview $xml and you'll have a cleaner version of the XML. For example: (left = before, right = after tidy)

[image]

Comment: Thanks.

Basically, the script that processes the XML, looks for the most recent XML in the directory. I have the XML i have manually uploaded, from saving in a browser, and then there is also the output from the above script, saved as download.xml. 

As the download.xml is most recent, the script loads this, but then doesnt work. If i delete the download.xml and let it find the file I saved using GoogleChrome, it works fine.

Here is an except of the script that processes the XML: ok it wont let me fit it all in here... 1400chars... How can I show you the script?

Comment: Edit your original question and add an excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

This is not "corruption". From what I can see from downloading this url, the source url does not use newlines consistently, and it does have long stretches of XML with no newlines.

In any case, the whitespace you are worried about is not significant to the XML and any script which breaks because of this whitespace is most likely not processing the XML correctly. (For example, it may be using regexes instead of a proper XML parser.)

The `copy()` function will give you a byte-for-byte copy of what it retrieves from the url--it will not "corrupt" it (as you say) by stripping newlines.  The fault probably lies with your processing script, which should not "break" because of this difference in newlines.

Comment: Thanks Francis. 
Basically,   the script that processes the XMl,  looks for the most recent XML in the directory.

I have the XML i have manually uploaded, from saving in a browse the above URL,  and then there is the output from the above script, saved as download.xml.   

As the download.xml is most recent, the script loads this,  but then doesnt work.  If i delete the download.xml and let it find the file I saved using GoogleChrome, it works fine.  

Here is an except of the script that processes the XML:
ok it wont let me fit it all in here...  1400chars...

How can I show you the script?

Comment: I would like to try your code above that tidys the XML,  but what is the last line needed to make it save the tidied xml as a file??